# Access all ports by domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, tomcat

I have a CentOS VPS running Tomcat on port 80 and HTTP on port 81.
I didn't know how to configure DNS. I searched and figured out there are websites that give you DNS. So I got DNS address from [cloudflare.com](http://cloudflare.com) and set it up on my domain. Now I can access my websites running on tomcat.

Everything works fine but I can't access other ports by typing domain names like:

```
example.com:81
```

But I can do it by typing:

```
192.0.2.1:81
```

So I want to know is there any way to access other ports by domain names or simply that is not possible and if not why?

Comment: What is the error you got when trying with MyDomain.com:81 ?

Comment: @krisFR nothing happens. just loading on browser

Comment: Is that somehow related to [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-)? Try to use port 8080 instead of 81 and test again.

Comment: My guess is the service you found is not actually a DNS service. If your VPS has IP address `192.0.2.1` and you got the domain name `example.com` hosted on a DNS service and pointing to your VPS, that would mean `example.com` resolves to `192.0.2.1`. If that was the case `http://example.com` would probably produce the same result as `http://192.0.2.1`. That's why I am guessing the service you found is not DNS but rather a proxy. And likely `example.com` resolves to a proxy such as `198.51.100.1` which only listens on port 80 and forwards the requests to `192.0.2.1`.

Comment: If your question provided real addresses, it would be possible to provide a definitive answer to the question and not just guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this seems to be related to that Cloudflare does proxying even DNS queries and only allows a limited amount of ports.
The available ports are listed on the [Cloudflare page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-).